# Expand an string based on values in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to expand a string with one or more values which come from an array.

Desired result:

```
http://example.com/search/key=["Start", "USA", "Minneapolis"]&shift=false
```

Array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "USA"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Minneapolis"


}
```

PHP Code:

```
$myArr = ("USA", "Minneapolis");
$string = 'http://example.com/search/key=["Start",' .$myArr[0]. ']&shift=false';
```

Gives me this result: `http://example.com/search/key=["Start", "USA"]&shift=false`

How can I make it more dynamic so that more than one value can be added? I know I somehow have to use a `foreach($myArr as $i){...}` and concatenate the values via `$string +=` but because my variable is in the middle of the string I'm kinda stuck with this approach.

Comment: Have you had a look at explode?

Comment: @MCMXCII I believe you mean `implode`

Comment: @mega6382 That's the one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$myArr = array("USA", "Minneapolis");

$string =  'http://example.com/search/key=["Start", "' . implode('", "', $myArr) . '"]&shift=false';
```

This will provide the expected output using `implode`.

Comment: Keep in mind, the SO question asker is not always right.  Come at each question with fresh eyes. Sometimes giving the OP exactly what they want is actually not good for them, SO content, and future SO readers.  p.s. When a question looks this easy, usually it means it should be closed as an unresearched duplicate and should be closed rather than answered.  I understand that you probably want to earn points as quickly as possible (I was the same way when I started this year), but try not to be too hasty.  Let's remember SO needs to be protected and respected as well. This is an archive of info.

Comment: @mickmackusa I most definitely agree with you, it is true that most of the reputation I have earned was in the past few weeks, but still in that few weeks I have deleted a dozen or so answers even the `accepted` and `upvoted` ones, because of low quality of the question. But still I get your point, that in an attempt to gain points quickly I should not loose sight for what SO represents.

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't right here.  You are trying to pass array data through a querystring but not in a valid array structure.  This means you are either not using it as an array on the next script and you are going to having to chop and hack at it when the data gets there.

I'll make the assumption that you would like to clean up your process...

Declare an array of all of the data that you want to pass through the url's query string, then merge the new `key` values into that subarray.  Finally, use `http_build_query()` to do ALL of the work of formatting/urlencoding everything then append that generated string after the `?` in your url.  This is THE clean, stable way to do it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qCj8K))

```
$myArr = ["USA", "Minneapolis", "monkey=wren[h"];

$data = [
    'key' => [
        'Start'
    ],
    'shift' => 'false'
];
$data['key'] = array_merge($data['key'], $myArr);

$url = 'http://example.com/search/?' . http_build_query($data);
echo "$url\n---\n";
echo urldecode($url);
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/search/?key%5B0%5D=Start&key%5B1%5D=USA&key%5B2%5D=Minneapolis&key%5B3%5D=monkey%3Dwren%5Bh&shift=false
---
http://example.com/search/?key[0]=Start&key[1]=USA&key[2]=Minneapolis&key[3]=monkey=wren[h&shift=false
```

*the decoded string is just to help you to visualize the output.

Then on your receiving page, you can simply and professionally access the `$_GET['key']` and `$_GET['shift']` data.

If you have a legitimate reason to use your original malformed syntax, I'd love to hear it.  Otherwise, please use my method for the sake of clean, valid web development.